# Cómo implementar sistema de cache en Retrofit, Android usando Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Estoy implementando `Retrofit` para llamadas a una `API` y me gustaría poder dar soporte offline mediante cache como hacen los browser, si no hay conexión tira de lo que hay en la cache.

```kotlin
object LightTariffAPIFactory {

    private val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .create()

    //OkhttpClient for building http request url
    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cache(myCache)
        .build()

    private fun retrofit(): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("my_url_api_rest")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()

    val API_REST: APIRestService =
        retrofit().create(APIRestService::class.java)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de agregar la propiedad, definiendo el tamaño del caché como al parecer lo tratas de realizar en tu código, por ejemplo para 10 MB:

```
    val cacheSize = (10 x 1024 x 1024).toLong()
    val myCache = Cache(context.cacheDir, cacheSize)

   vprivate val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(myCache)
                ...
                ...
                ...
```